# mysqldump with character issues

Tags: mysql

php code:

```
exec('mysqldump --opt --compress --host='.DB_HOST.' --user='.DB_USER.' --password='.DB_PASS.' '.DB_NAME.' > file.sql');
```

some characters are not being exported as they are in the DB. For example "ñ" becomes "Ã±" -- am i missing a parameter in the mysqldump instruction? BTW, the DB is utf8. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [How to keep special characters when running ./mysqldump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574900/how-to-keep-special-characters-when-running-mysqldump)

Try adding the switch: `--default-character-set=UTF8`

Comment: i did. nothing =( characters are still displaying garbage.